# Grunt concat html and js with different separators?

Tags: html, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

Currently I am concatenating my Javascript files using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) as follows:

```
concat: {
    options: {
        separator: ';'
    },
    js: {
        src: [
            '...'
        ],
        dest: 'main.js',
        nonull: true
    }
}
```

This works great. However I also want to concatenate some HTML files, and do this first.

However if I add a separate task, e.g.

```
concat: {
    options: {
        separator: ';'
    },
    js: {
        src: [
            '...'
        ],
        dest: 'main.js',
        nonull: true
    },
    html: {
        src: [
            '...'
        ],
        dest: 'partials.html'
    }
}
```

It will use the same `;` separator inbetween each HTML file...

I cannot see anything in the documentation and examples that would help me.

I suppose I could use a separate plugin, maybe something like [grunt-html-build](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build) but that seems a bit complicated when all I want to do is concatenate them.

I may want to use [grunt-contrib-htmlmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) or similar afterwards as well, so that is worth bearing in mind.

Is it worth the hassle/overhead just to manually check each script to ensure it ends with a semi-colon?

What is the best way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not specify a different separator depending on the target?

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    html: {
      options: {
        separator: " whatever "
      },
      src: []
    },
    js: {
      options: {
        separator: ";\n"
      },
      src: []
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work, but I've just tried it again and it is adding the separator in. *Facepalm* thanks

Comment: Sometimes, all it takes to have things work is someone else stating the obvious out loud. That's not exactly rubber duck debugging, but kind of the same idea :-) Happy it helped!